# Issue regarding running Sawtooth docker-compose image

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am following the steps as mention in the following documentation:
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/docker.html

I am on a Ubuntu 20.04 system.
On running `docker-compose -f sawtooth.yaml up` where sawtooth.yaml is the mentioned yaml file in the docs, I am getting the output like this:

```
sawtooth-validator-default | [2020-08-09 08:09:44.255 DEBUG    interconnect] No response from 26aad11ecd9741f6f4c28988390d2fbf3c6bfd0fa0c85d1226472f06944c42cf01969f8679cd3bfdeb4bb6484d8a9c4e624130cd4dcdc59f9c7a9e9a8970ef20 in 10.003934144973755 seconds - beginning heartbeat pings.
sawtooth-xo-tp-python-default | [2020-08-09 08:09:44.255 DEBUG    core] received message of type: PING_REQUEST
sawtooth-intkey-tp-python-default | [2020-08-09 08:09:44.262 DEBUG    core] received message of type: PING_REQUEST
sawtooth-settings-tp-default | INFO  | sawtooth_sdk::proces | Message: b7f0c91bb498439cb5334a25c5e71b0d
sawtooth-settings-tp-default | INFO  | sawtooth_sdk::proces | sending PingResponse
sawtooth-validator-default | [2020-08-09 08:09:54.268 DEBUG    interconnect] No response from f2e0ae558284f294ed0e10ec545e4824e6a23a3ad15227e48ac1dd9d4e56fe7d72b64acc9646c6dc1832ffb203f3e610bc2d2f20a63536c12b7897b71406bd95 in 10.000118017196655 seconds - beginning heartbeat pings.
sawtooth-xo-tp-python-default | [2020-08-09 08:09:54.274 DEBUG    core] received message of type: PING_REQUEST
sawtooth-validator-default | [2020-08-09 08:10:04.271 DEBUG    interconnect] No response from 928677470a149124decb0ea1d4c57c27a7f2be1e7d78ff4372fa86f0838645d1be8627e0a7d69a5386e918d2c19ca38b224e369507723432df2322dcdffc238e in 19.99619770050049 seconds - beginning heartbeat pings.
sawtooth-intkey-tp-python-default | [2020-08-09 08:10:04.273 DEBUG    core] received message of type: PING_REQUEST
sawtooth-settings-tp-default | INFO  | sawtooth_sdk::proces | Message: ec83258d2c394b45b0de32696c4290bd
sawtooth-settings-tp-default | INFO  | sawtooth_sdk::proces | sending PingResponse
sawtooth-validator-default | [2020-08-09 08:10:14.283 DEBUG    interconnect] No response from 928677470a149124decb0ea1d4c57c27a7f2be1e7d78ff4372fa86f0838645d1be8627e0a7d69a5386e918d2c19ca38b224e369507723432df2322dcdffc238e in 10.008570909500122 seconds - beginning heartbeat pings.
```

I couldn't find anything regarding such message in the docs.

Someone pls guide me, whether I did something wrong or is everything working properly??

Comment: There has been attempt to capture this in the FAQ section of the Sawtooth website. Please find the information here https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-website/pull/57/files